# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000 when hitting Docker containerised Node.js app endpoint

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm just starting with Docker and dough I succeed in creating an image and a container from it
I'm not succeeding in connecting to the container's port with postman and I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000`.

In my server.js file I have:

```
const app = require('./api/src/app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // PORT is set to 5000

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('App executing to port ', port);
});
```

in my index.js I have :

```
const express = require('express');

 const router = express.Router();
 
 router.get('/api', (req, res) => {
   res.status(200).send({
     success: 'true',
     message: 'Welcome to fixit',
     version: '1.0.0',
   });
 });
 
 module.exports = router;
```

so if I run my app with either `npm start` or `nodemon server.js` the `localhost:3000/api` endpoint works as expected.

I then build a docker image for my app with the command `docker build . -t fixit-server` with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15.14.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

# CMD ["npm", "start"]
CMD npm start
# CMD ["nodemon", "server.js"]
```

and run the container with the command `docker run -d -p 8000:5000 --name fixit-container fixit-server tail -f /dev/null`

and listing the containers with `docker ps -a` shows it running :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
da0e4ef12402   fixit-server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 seconds ago   Up 8 seconds   0.0.0.0:8000->5000/tcp   fixit-container
```

but when I hit the endpoint `0.0.0.0:8000/api`I get the ECONNREFUSED error.
I tried both `CMD ["npm", "start"]`and `CMD npm start` but I get the error both ways.
Can you what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you `docker run ... tail -f /dev/null`?  That "do-nothing" command runs instead of your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

@Vincenzo was using `docker-machine` and to be able to check whether the app was working properly, we needed to execute the following command in the terminal:

```sh
docker-machine env
```

The result was:

```sh
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.102:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/vinnytwice/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

Then based on the `DOCKER_HOST` value, we hit `192.168.99.102:8000/api` and it was working.

---

I believe the problem is you're never setting the `PORT` environment variable to `5000`.

`EXPOSE` docker command is a no op. Meaning that it will do nothing but is only for the developer to know that you're exposing the port 5000. You can read it in [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

You need to either set an environment variable or pass an environment variable at runtime to the container to specifically tell it that `PORT` is 5000.

#### Method 1:

You can change your Dockerfile like below:

```
FROM node:15.14.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV PORT=5000

EXPOSE $PORT

# CMD ["npm", "start"]
CMD npm start
# CMD ["nodemon", "server.js"]
```

#### Method 2:

Simply use the following command to run your container:

```sh
docker run -d -p 8000:5000 --name fixit-container --env PORT=5000 fixit-server
```

Comment: @Vincenzo Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: unfortunately is behaving the same..
I tried both methods and again both `CMD ["npm", "start"]`and `CMD npm start` but no luck here..

Comment: Did you try to connect using `127.0.0.1:8000/api`? Also, if you have Docker Desktop installed, can you check the log of your container? You can also get the logs of your container using `docker logs <container_id>`

Comment: Yes I did try, and it doesn't work either, I'm on an older Mac so I can't use Docker desktop, I use docker-machine

Comment: Cool, first, could you stop the current container. And then use this command to run the container again `docker run -p 8000:5000 --name fixit-container --env PORT=5000 fixit-server`. Then you should be able to see the logs in your terminal

Comment: Ok I tried and I get this error: `/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/main.js:243
        throw new TypeError(`Invalid connection details: ` + npm.utils.toJson(cn));`

Comment: can it be because I have `node_modules` in my `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232478/discussion-between-eranga-heshan-and-vincenzo).